# Front-End API Token Exposure

Tags: javascript, api

My question is simple and general: when making calls to RESTFUL APIs, whether they be mine or external ones, is it common practice/ok to have the token exposed on the front end? For instance, in the documentation for the Google Maps api, they suggest the following code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

the fact that your API key is exposed on the front end for all to see is ok then? I guess google has has the option to restrict access, so that can solve that, but what about other services that don't give that option?

Is it better to keep my API calls on the backend to protect my tokens? Having them on the backend, I would think, would not be preferred, because they I cannot get the data asynchronously

Comment: don't know if it is important for you. but if you use google maps api on a homepage the key can (should) be registred to the url calling from. so it senseless to capture this key for use with other domains.

Comment: Yeah I more meant for other apis that don't offer that level of security

Answer (score 0):

In short , yes it's possible to use someone else API keys in your site if you can spoof http referer header on client system .In fact you can even saturate his quota completely if you have either of these

1. Full control over your clients browser (to manipulate HTTP headers it might send to google servers)
2. You own huge collection of unique IP adresses (try only if you're freakingly rich and only motive you're left with in life is to empty his quota xD)
3. Idk atm will tell if i learn something more or someone comments something